# Validar una condición con un trigger a la hora de insertar en una tabla. mySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Quiero insertar unos datos en una tabla, pero tienen que cumplir que la suma de las proporciones de los datos con el mismo código tiene que ser 100.
Mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS impregnaciones(
nombre_e VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
codigo_rexpl CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
proporcion INT(3)   NOT NULL
);
```

Mi trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER checkpropocion  BEFORE INSERT ON impregnaciones FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
declare proporcion_r INT;
SELECT  sum(NEW.proporcion) INTO proporcion_r
FROM impregnaciones
GROUP BY new.codigo_rexpl;
IF( proporcion_r  != 100 ) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='La proporción no se cumple';
END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Pero a la hora de insertar los datos da igual que se cumpla o no la proporción que siempre entra en el if y me salta 'La proporción no se cumple'

Comment: No te falta el else que seria la parte que cuando si cumple ?.

Comment: Cuando no se cumple el if no queremos que haga nada, por ello no escribimos un else. La cuestión es que siempre entra al if se cumpla o no la condición. Muchas gracias.